# Second Order Differential Equation Repeated Eigen Values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation I am trying to solve is 
$$
\dfrac{d^2y}{dt^2} + 2\dfrac{dy}{dt} + 1y = \cos(3t)
$$
I know how to start off. I have done the $s^2 + 2s + 1 = 0$ to get $s = -1$

I understand how to do the solution for the right hand side, but with repeated eigenvalues how do i find the homogenous solution for the left hand side?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard situation. When the indicial equation has a repeated root $\lambda$, you have $e^{\lambda t}$ and $te^{\lambda t}$ as solutions.

Comment: I know that when dealing with matrices you have $e^{\lambda t}V_o + te^{\lambda t}V_1$ Do I not need to worry about the V's

Comment: This is a scalar ODE. Perhaps you saw in your class how to solve it by converting to a first-order system, where the vectors would have emerged.

Comment: What is often passed over in introductory ODE courses is that the "power of $t$ rule" comes from the variation of parameters method (which gets skipped over frequently).  If you know the one solution from the characteristic equation, $e^{-t}$, you could construct a second solution of the form $u(t) \cdot e^{-t}$. Inserting this into the homogeneous DE (and applying the Product Rule) tells us that $u'' = 0 \Rightarrow u = Ct$, making our second solution $Cte^{-t}$.